# I want to fetch images from firebase storage and show them in a pdf created using pdf package

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have fetched all images URL from firebase storage but not able to show them in the pdf

```
List<String> imageUrls = [];

String path = 'gs://tp-zap-solz.appspot.com/SafetyChecklist/Bengaluru/BMTC KR Puram-29/ZW3210/1';
ListResult result = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path).listAll();

for (var item in result.items) {
  String downloadUrl = await item.getDownloadURL();
  imageUrls.add(downloadUrl);
}

print('Firestorage List : ${imageUrls.length} $imageUrls');
```

I have tried many ways but not able to show this image_urls in pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented the same thing but without getting the images from Firebase.

```
final pdf = pdf_widgets.Document();

   for (var file in _path) {
     final image = pdf_widgets.MemoryImage(File(file).readAsBytesSync());
        pdf.addPage(pdf_widgets.Page(
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
           build: (pdf_widgets.Context context) {
            return pdf_widgets.Center(
                child: pdf_widgets.Image(image)
            );
           }
        ));
      }
```

Using [this pub](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf).

First, create a list of images and use a for-loop to iterate through all the images. Using the pub you have the possibility to add these images ad pdf pages directly using everything the pub offers.

If this doesn't help you, please let me know and I'll provide more support to you, happy coding!